# Security of apps using faceId/touchId? How does it work?

Tags: java, android, ios, authentication, authorization

In my country we have a MFA service that for instance, can take in your mobile phone number, and then pings your phone, you enter a pin and you're authenticated. The app that calls this service gets back your "social security number" equivalent.

In apps this can be used as follows:

- You open the app for the first time. Enter your phone number and authenticate.
- The app might let you pick a pin as well, but after this first log in it won't prompt you to use this MFA again, it will use your face id or your touchId

How does this work?

Here's one guess:

- During registration, the MFA service is called, it gets your "social security number" and uses that as your username
- The pin you entered (perhaps only 4 letters - very short, so this makes me doubt this theory) is then used as your password
- The username and password (pin) are then stored in your key chain / core storage, and the app prompts you for faceId/touchId but then sends your user/pin to authenticate you with the API

Is this how it works? And if so, isn't a 4 digit pin too insecure? I'm assuming if you can use that to authenticate then anyone that can access your API can attempt to brute force it. And since it's an API being used by an app, that means it's open to everyone.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit: I guess a secret could be generated for each user, and the pin could be encrypted using that secret, making it longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most modern and secure ways of doing this do not involve sharing your secret (pin) with the relying part (backend) but using asymmetric key encryption. 
For example, my guess would be:

**During registration**

- You authenticate successfully with your credentials.
- The device generates a key pair using the Secure Enclave and makes it only accessible using biometrics (TouchID, FaceID).
- The public key is sent to the backend.

**During authentication**

- The backend sends a challenge to the device through some channel (push notification?)
- The device signs the challenge using the private key created during registration, and sends it to the backend.
- The backend validates the signature and gives you access to the protected resource.

That is the basic security I would expect for modern application like that.

> Is this how it works? And if so, isn't a 4 digit pin too insecure? I'm assuming if you can use that to authenticate then anyone that can access your API can attempt to brute force it. And since it's an API being used by an app, that means it's open to everyone.

I am not sure why they ask you for the PIN. Maybe they want to apply some extra protection and do things like:

- Lock the application in case the biometric authentication wasn't successful. The PIN can be used to unlock the application and let you try again.
- Use the PIN as authentication method in case the user has biometric authentication methods disabled.

In any case, and even though 4 digits is too little, the PIN is normally hashed using a key derivation function (like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)) to make an attacker slower and prevent brute force attacks. The actual PIN is never stored, but the hash.

All these security schemes are being standardised now, in an effort to have secure enough products. If you feel adventurous, you can take a look a the FIDO UAF protocol:
https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-uaf-v1.1-id-20170202/fido-uaf-overview-v1.1-id-20170202.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply crom, it's very detailed and clear. Do you by any chance have any knowledge of Azure AD B2C? Do you know how that would work with an MFA like the one I described?